# Computing correlation/distance between two laplacian spectra (histogram)

Tags: histogram, distance, graph-theory

I have several laplacian spectra of graphs (networks) to compare, and I'm looking for a distance measure between each pair of spectrum.

I have tried Hellinger distance and euclidian distance (the n-dimensionnal euclidian distance between two vectors of eigenvalues, where n is the number of bins), which give me different distances, obviously, but also different rankings, which leads me to think that the method used is quite important in the quality of the results.

I also saw that histograms distances can be measured through other methods (correlation, chi-square, intersection, heart mover's distance, etc.)

Is there an accepted distance measure for this kind of histogram comparison problem, **where relatively small features are quite important** (like the peaks around eigenvalue 0.3) ?

The spectra:

[image]